# org-agenda just choose with the default keys

Tags: org-agenda

These days I am using org-agenda to manage my todo lists. Does there exist some settings that just let the agenda-view choose a specified one. For example, when I use the `org-agenda` command, it shows a menu and says: "Press key for an agenda command". Since in most cases, I just choose "a", I am wondering whether there exists a setting to skip the choose and just call one of the listed commands.

Comment: The question doesn't seem too clear. Maybe someone familiar with Org can clarify it a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite simple to define your own keybindings.

At first you need to know what command is called by `org-agenda` `a`.
The documentation string of `org-agenda` reveals that (just type <kbd>C-h f</kbd> `org-agenda` <kbd>RET</kbd>). You will see that `a` is bound to `org-agenda-list`.

Now you can define your preferred keybinding in [your initialization file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) with

```el
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (local-set-key (kbd "C-c a") #'org-agenda-list)))
```

Afterwards you can call `org-agenda-list` with <kbd>C-c a</kbd>.

Note, that the bindings with prefix <kbd>C-c</kbd> are reserved for mode-local keybindings.

Furthermore, keybindings <kbd>C-c</kbd> followed by a letter without modifiers are reserved for the user (i.e., for you). They should never be used by libraries. So you can safely use them for your purpose.